# How do I assign variables to items in a ASCII file and calculate them in C++?

Tags: c++, fstream

I have been told to have a list in a text file that contains the following information:

```
Chisel 50 9.99  Hammer 30  15.99    Nails 2000 0.99
Bolts  200 2.99    Nuts  300  1.99  Soap 55 1.89
```

I have written this program to open the file.. and I have no idea on how to assign an item like "chisel" to a variable in the program, so I can multiply the amount by the price to output the total price.

```
    cout << "----Make sure that the appropriate text file is located \nin the same directory as this program----" << endl;
    cout << "\nNow enter the name of the text file, followed by " << ".txt" << endl;
    string item;
    int var1;
    int var2;
    int var3;
    char filename[50];
    ifstream wolf;  //object name
    cin.getline(filename, 50);
    wolf.open(filename);

    if (!wolf.is_open()){
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    char word[50];
    wolf >> word;
    while (wolf.good()){
        cout << word << " ";
        wolf >> word;
    }


    while (wolf >> item >> var1 >> var2 >> var3)
    {
        cout << item << var1 << var2 << var3 << endl;
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you heard of a know how to use a `struct` or `class`?

Comment: BTW Don't use `while (wolf.good())`.  Just use `while (wolf >> word)`

Comment: What's with all the `char` arrays?

Comment: no we have not learned of struct or class i dont think.

Comment: Please search StackOverflow for "c++ read file double".  There are a *plethora* of existing examples.

Comment: This should be closed as a duplicate, but because the data file format is different, it doesn't *exactly* match an existing question. :-(

Comment: i am really confused on this assignment :((

Comment: *"i am really confused"* - we can tell.  Consider: `double price; int qty; std::string item; if (std::ifstream in(filename)) while (in >> item >> qty >> price) std::cout << "total for " << item << "s is " << qty * price << '\n'; else std::cerr << "unable to open '" << filename << "'\n";`

Comment: what is the phrase "if (std::ifstream in(filename))" doing exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Dude seriously use `delimiter` next time , below is the code that is feasible solution but not optimal. This code read `text` file and copy `item name` like `chisel` into the `item_name[20]` array , copy `quantity of item` like `50` into the `qty` and also copy `rate of item` like `9.99` into `rate` and then calculate total price by calculating `qty*rate` that you want . There are many variables used here so watch them carefully.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct List
{
   char item_name[20];
   int qty;
   float rate;
}
List[20];

ifstream file;
int main()
{

    int i,j,y,l,z,null;
    l=j=0;z=-1;
    char filename[10];
    char line[80];char number[21];

    for(y=0;y<80;y++)
    {
      line[y]=NULL;
    }
    cout<<"Enter file name : ";
    cin>>filename;
    file.open(filename,ios::in);
    if(!file)
    {
      cerr<<"File does not exist !!!";
      exit(0);
    }
    while(file.getline(line,80))
    {
      z=z+1;j=0;
        i=strlen(line);
        for(y=0;y<i;y++)
        {
          if(isalpha(line[y]))
          { List[z].item_name[j]=line[y];j=j+1;}
          if(line[y]==' ')
          {
              for(null=0;null<=20;null++)
              {
                  number[null]=NULL;
              }
             if(isalpha(line[y-1]))
             {
                  l=1;j=0;
             }
             if(isdigit(line[y-1]))
             {
               l=2;j=0;
             }
             if(isalpha(line[y+1]))
             {
                  z=z+1;
             }
          }
          if(isdigit(line[y])||(line[y]=='.'))
          {
              number[j]=line[y];
              if(l==1)
              {
                  List[z].qty=atoi(number);
              }
             if((l==2)||(line[y]=='.'))
             {
                  List[z].rate=atof(number);
             }
             j=j+1;
           }
        }
    }
    file.close();

    for(y=0;y<=z;y++)
    {
       //cout<<List[y].item_name<<" "<<List[y].qty<<" "<<List[y].rate<<endl;
       cout<<"Name of item : "<<List[y].item_name<<" Qty of this item : "<<List[y].qty<<" Rate of this item : "<<List[y].rate;
       cout<<"\nPrice = Qty of item * Rate of this item = "<<List[y].qty*List[y].rate<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code takes my more than 5 hours - "use `delimiter` next time":)